# SQL String query with using container

Tags: java, sql

```
// First 
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableNAME + " where kelimeGrubu = 'test' ";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

//Second
String str = "test"
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableNAME + " where kelimeGrubu = " + str;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

This is my code , first one is working fine without problems. But I need the second one which is giving `runtime error`, what could be the problem?

Comment: is 'test' the same as `test` ?

Comment: @OmerK where condition value should have single quotes surrounded for query to work

Comment: yes, it is only a string,

Comment: Please do **not** concatenate values into SQL strings. Learn how to properly use a PreparedStatement

Answer (score 1):

You're not quoting the string in the SQL statement in the second example. Your built SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableNAME where kelimeGrubu = test
```

...but since `test` is not a column name, you get a runtime query error. You can solve this by a prepared statement:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM " + tableNAME + " WHERE kelimeGrubu = ?",
    new String[] { str }
);
```

...which also prevents potential SQL injection attacks when `str` is potentially user-controlled.

Comment: "test" is only a string, same is "qqq" for exemple, I need user-control

Comment: That's fine -- this code takes `str` as a variable, so it can be user-controlled safely. Binding the string to a parameter in a parameterized query like this is safe and avoids quoting issues.

Comment: I didn't understand

Answer (score -1):

instead of this

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableNAME+" where kelimeGrubu = " + str ;
```

write this one

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableNAME+" where kelimeGrubu = '" + str +"'" ;
```

Comment: This is unsafe, because it is vulnerable to SQL injection.